# Robot FrameWork, Clink Link does not handle link with "=" and results in "Link with locator is not found"

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I have a problem that I failed to solve. I am trying to navigate as (I have anonymized it a bit, used Crome plugin 'Robotcorder' to capture)

```
Click Link   //a[@href="https://xxx.yyy.com/psp/zzzzprd/EMPLOYEE/ERP/s/WEBLIB_PTPP_SC.HOMEPAGE.FieldFormula.IScript_AppHP?scname=XX_YYYYYY_TE_CENTER&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.CO_AAAAA_BB_SERVICE.EP_SC_UU_BBBBB_TE_CENTER&IsFolder=false&IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder"]
```

---

but it always fails with "Link with locator is not found".

I tested with:

- Click Element
- replacing "=" with "%3D"
- default=https...
- link=https
- ...

If have of course searched the web and found a lot of suggestions and tried to test them all.

If I paste the link in the browser address it navigates as intended.

The webpage is built round some kind of Oracle framework that we are using for time reporting and I just wanted to test Robot WorkFramework to enter a weeks time.

Comment: The reference you're giving is an xpath reference. Although the `//a[@href=".."]` might work, it's often not the sturdiest of references. Is there perhaps a parent element with a unique Id that you can refer to? Like `//div[@id="123"]//a`.

Answer (score 2):

Fromt the [Click Link documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Click%20Link):

> When using the default locator strategy, links are searched using id, name, href and the link text.

Because you didn't specify the locator strategy, robot will try to find a link with an id, name, or href that exactly matches the string "//a[@href=...". Since what you provided isn't an id, name, or href, it won't find your link.

If you want to look up the link using an xpath, you need to tell the keyword that you're giving it an xpath. with older versions of the selenium library you would prefix it with `xpath=`, with newer versions you should use `xpath:`.

Example:

```
Click Link  xpath://a[@href="https://xxx.yyy.com/psp/zzzzprd/EMPLOYEE/ERP/s/WEBLIB_PTPP_SC.HOMEPAGE.FieldFormula.IScript_AppHP?scname=XX_YYYYYY_TE_CENTER&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.CO_AAAAA_BB_SERVICE.EP_SC_UU_BBBBB_TE_CENTER&IsFolder=false&IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder"]
```

Since you're only using the href to identify the link, you can shorten this slighly by providing just the href:

```
Click Link  href:https://xxx.yyy.com/psp/zzzzprd/EMPLOYEE/ERP/s/WEBLIB_PTPP_SC.HOMEPAGE.FieldFormula.IScript_AppHP?scname=XX_YYYYYY_TE_CENTER&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.CO_AAAAA_BB_SERVICE.EP_SC_UU_BBBBB_TE_CENTER&IsFolder=false&IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder
```

I would encourage you to try to find a better way to identify that link rather than with that exceptionally long, hard to read URL. For example, you or one of your developers should add a unique id or name attribute to the link to make it easier to test.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. Unfortnatly am I part of a big organization so changing the link is probably not an option.

Comment: And here is the true link:
"
'href:https://capf9prd.capco.com/psp/capf9prd/EMPLOYEE/ERP/s/WEBLIB_PTPP_SC.HOMEPAGE.FieldFormula.IScript_AppHP?scname=EP_EMPLOYEE_TE_CENTER&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.CO_EMPLOYEE_SELF_SERVICE.EP_SC_SP_EMPLOYEE_TE_CENTER&IsFolder=false&IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder' not found.
"